# Istio on Azure Kubernetes Service?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, istio, azure-aks

I am reviewing Azure Kubernetes Service for my current employer and trying to determine if there are any limitations to using istio on AKS. Does anyone have any experience doing so? Does it work as normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some information for you to refer.

In the article of [Quick start instructions to install and configure Istio in a Kubernetes cluster](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/quick-start) , you will find the **Prerequisites** of using Istio in a Kubernetes cluster.

> The following instructions recommend you have access to a Kubernetes 1.9 or newer cluster **with RBAC (Role-Based Access Control) enabled**. You will also need kubectl 1.9 or newer installed.

But in AKS, RBAC is currently not supported in AKS, you could pay attention on it. It will be available soon. Refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#does-aks-support-kubernetes-role-based-access-control-rbac).

In Azure, you also can use [ACS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-walkthrough) which is an older version of AKS, but with control over Kubernetes master or [acs-engine](https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine) where you have full control over Kubernetes cluster.

Or for installing the Istio incubator package with RBAC disabled, refer to this [article](https://readon.ly/post/2017-05-25-deploy-istio-to-azure-container-service/).

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic answer Joy!

Answer (score 1):

AKS now supports Kubernetes RBAC, so Istio should work as expected. Note, however, that RBAC is not enabled by default yet and cannot yet be turned on via the Azure portal, so you will need to use the az cli like so:

`az aks create -n mycluster -g myresourcegroup --enable-rbac`

Answer (score 0):

Istio would work with AKS normally.
Check doc from [Istio](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/platform-setup/azure/) and [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/istio-install)